# Why does installing one npm package add many subfolders in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, path, npm, dependencies

I've updated node / npm which I use with my grunt projects.

However when I now want to add a package to a project `myproject/` (say `npm install grunt-favicon`) it seems to add hundreds of folders to `myproject/node_modules/` whereas it only used to add one - normally prefixed with grunt like `node_modules/grunt-favicon`.

My knowledge of these things is basic but these seem to be required dependencies, and even some of these items have even more dependencies.

Should it not be adding these dependencies somewhere else? If so how to i correct this?

I use `npm 3.3.5`, `node 4.1.1`, `grunt-cli v0.1.13` and `grunt v0.4.5`.

And this screenshot shows `~/.npm` on the left then `~/myproject/node_modules` on the right

[image: ~/.npm on the left then]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is correct, don't worry. You're still installing the packages locally, just the directory structure looks a bit different. It is a behaviour that **changed in npm v3.0.0**: now all the dependencies' dependencies are installed directly in the `node_modules` folder (as far as this doesn't cause version conflicts). This greatly reduces the file tree size.

From [npm 3.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases?after=v2.12.1):

> #### Flat, flat, flat!
>
> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

Comment: thanks m01 - i thought if these were global (in ~/.npm) just once that would save them having to be duplicated in every project/node_modules/ folder?

Comment: No. Here the point is not to install dependencies of dependencies of your project many times. For example, in npm v2, a fresh install of `gulp-imagemin` contains 59 copies of the `stream` module, in various places in the `node_modules` directory tree. Ridiculous, isn't it? Now, with npm v3 you'll get only a single copy.

Comment: I get ya - i was thinking about the node_modules repeated in different projects...

Comment: @m01 what if I want to force install with a nested dependency tree? like if package **A**, which isn't aware of npm@v3's behavior and is dependent on package **B**, assumes **B** will be installed in `/node_modules/A/node_modules/B` instead of `/node_modules/B`?

Comment: I guess you found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321181/how-can-i-force-npm-3-to-install-nested-dependencies ;)

Comment: This forum has just helped me out - great question and answer! What happens though, say, if package A depends on package C@1.1.1 and package B depends on package C@2.2.2?  In this case, which version of package `C` would get installed in this new flat-like structure? (how conflict of dependencies are handled?). disclaimer - I am no npm expert!

Comment: If there is a conflict, they will be nested as in npm 2.x. To quote the release notes again, "You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies".