# how can I force npm 3 to install nested dependencies?

Tags: module, npm, dependencies, package, dependency-management

I just upgraded to [npm version 3](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.3.9) and noticed one of the biggest changes it made is that it enforces a [flat dependency tree](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0).

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's `node_modules` folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

So for example if package **A** is dependent on package **B**, when you `npm install A` you will get this file structure:

```
--- root/
 |--- node_modules/
   |--- A/
   |--- B/
```

instead of the old file structure from version 2 or lower:

```
--- root/
 |--- node_modules/
   |--- A/
     |--- node_modules/
       |--- B/
```

The first (and I’m sure not the last) problem I ran into was this:

Package **A** isn’t aware of npm v3’s behavior and is dependent on package **B**. But **A** assumes the old (v2) file structure because it has `node_modules/B` in its code, instead of the proper `../node_modules/B`. Now the code from **A** won’t compile because it’s looking for `B/` in the wrong directory.

If I don’t feel like nagging the developer to fix the code and waiting for an update of **A**, I wonder if there’s a way I can set an option that will force npm to install **A**’s dependencies inside its own `node_modules` folder, the same way npm v2 would have done it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried `--legacy-bundling` for `npm install`?

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

> The --legacy-bundling argument will cause npm to install the package such that versions of npm prior to 1.4, such as the one included with node 0.8, can install the package. This eliminates all automatic deduping.

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens when I don’t get enough sleep. The obvious solution somehow escaped me.

```
$ cd node_modules/A/
$ npm install
$ cd ../../
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue and I hope there's a better solution because going with this one you'll have to: `cd node_modules/A && npm install` then `cd node_modules/A/node_modules/B && npm install` and so on... From what I understood, all packages MUST follow the new way npm handle dependencies before they can work with npm 3.0, right?

Comment: @Gabin as far as I know, you are correct. It makes upgrading dependencies a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into this issue and found an alternative to fix this issue. Since Node.js comes with NPM, the only way that I could think of was to downgrade to Node.js 0.10 version, which comes with an older version on NPM, which will install dependencies in the old fashion way. To downgrade I used [NVM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm) and ran `nvm use 0.10.0`. You can switch back and forth between npm versions by following this trick. Hope it helps!

Comment: I will try this and see if it works. Also I believe your statement "NPM comes with Node.js" is false; it's the other way around. Node comes installed with npm.

Comment: Yeah. I just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I think the wording was just confusing. Because when you say "npm comes with node," that could mean *npm comes installed with node*, that is, when you install npm you automatically get node (incorrect); or that *npm comes installed along with node*, i.e. installing node will give you a copy of npm (correct). English is stupid.