# npm v4 module installation location/configuration

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way to have node_modules maintain their module structure on installation (like npm v3 and below) instead of installing all dependencies of a module at the same directory level as that module.

e.g. running:

```
npm install express
```

will install all the dependencies of express like so

```
node_modules
    ...
    express    
    ...
```

as opposed to before where the dependencies of express maintained their structure like so:

```
node_modules
    express
        node_modules
           ...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I force npm 3 to install nested dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321181/how-can-i-force-npm-3-to-install-nested-dependencies)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you!! @dvlsg

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install <module> --legacy-bundling
```