# Installing node modules cleanly in the node_modules directory

Tags: node.js

On my last installation of Node.js, all the modules were located in C:\localhost\node\node_modules, but the only folders present were the modules I had installed, such as /memcached etc.

when I reinstalled node and use npm to install modules again, it appears as if it installs all its dependent modules in the same directory, causing the node_modules directory to become heavily populated.

This makes it a mess to see which ones are installed directly, any idea how to get back to the old way?

Comment: why don't you use git init and package.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I force npm 3 to install nested dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321181/how-can-i-force-npm-3-to-install-nested-dependencies)